# Solving a bi-level formulation with no closed form for its second level

Tags: optimization

I was wondering if I can receive your suggestions regarding how to solve a bi-level formulation with no closed form for its second level.

I can solve the second level, separately, using a heuristic projection algorithm.

I studied some metaheuristics to solve both levels, but I am looking for an exact, heuristic approach, or any approach that can provide some properties for the solution quality (even in specific conditions for other or general problems).

Thanks for your help in advance,